# How to get parentContentControls from current selection in word add-in

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I am developing a word add-in using word javascript api and need to get contentControl for current selection, so used parentContentControl for current selection.

```
**Code:**    
var range = context.document.getSelection().parentContentControl;
context.load(range);
```

But on console it showing error:
Error: `{"name":"OfficeExtension.Error","code":"GeneralException","message":"GeneralException","traceMessages":[],"debugInfo":{"errorLocation":"Range.parentContentControl"},"stack":"GeneralException: GeneralException\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:189006)\n   at pi (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:211583)\n   at ht (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:211670)\n   at g (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:211490)\n   at l (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:210076)"}`

```
Debug info: {"errorLocation":"Range.parentContentControl"}
```

If the current selection not contain any contentControl it should return NULL, but it giving error. Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question and goes to one of the core concepts of the office.js technology: how do we handle nulls? The long story short is that whenever there *is a possibility* that a method/property returns null, we offer to flavors of that method/property:

1. Default. No special suffix. If the returning value is null (in this case there is no content control surrounding the selection) this flavor immediately throws an exception, as correctly described on your question. That's by design.
2. Returns a "Null Object". They have a *OrNullObject suffix. This flavor does **NOT** throw an exception, but returns a way to verify if the object is null or not. (note in this context this 'null object' is different than the JavaScript null, please do not confuse by this)

The second flavor is available starting on the November fork (builds 16.0.7668+), so please make sure to update your clients to see this working.

So to concretely answer your question: that behavior is by design. If you want to validate existence of a content control within the selection you need to use the range.parentContentControlOrNullObject property. Then you can check if its null or not. Here is an example of how you can accomplish this:

```js
var myCC = context.document.getSelection().parentContentControlOrNullObject; // this flavor will not throw an exception.
            context.load(myCC);
            return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (myCC.isNullObject)  // when using this flavor of the property you will get a isNullObject to check if its null or not and act accordingly.
                   console.log("There is no content control sorrounding");
                else
                    app.showNotification("there is a content control wrapping the selection.");

            })
               .catch(function (e) {
                         console.log(e.message);

                       })



        })
```

Hope this clarifies the concept

Comment: @Balmori Thankyou for reply in detail, i have tried above code but still getting error:Error: {"description":"Unable to get property '_objectPath' of undefined or null reference","number":-2146823281,"stack":"TypeError: Unable to get property '_objectPath' of undefined or null reference\n   at t.validateObjectPath (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:220526)\n   at t.createQueryAction (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js:19:180827)\n   at i.prototype.load (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js..

Comment: My Office JavaScript API library: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js

Comment: What's your office build ? Make sure you are on latest

Comment: @Balmori I am using above office Api Library and it showing Version: 16.0.7805.1000.

Comment: My MS word client Version: 1612 (Build 7678.2066). Please advice.

Comment: We are about to make an update to the live CDN, can you please try with the beta location at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

Comment: Thanks, it works using beta, when you will update on live?
One more thing, i just want to confirm that before 1 month my code was working fine and it stopped so it is due to word client update or javascript Api Library?

Comment: Hello it was working well but after i upgraded my system to Windows 10 and install office 365 & visual studio, It is showing me error: Error: {"name":"OfficeExtension.Error","code":"GeneralException","message":"GeneralException","traceMessages":[],"innerError":null,"debugInfo":{"code":"GeneralException","message":"GeneralException","errorLocation":"Range.parentContentControlOrNullObject"},"stack":"GeneralException. Please advise.

Comment: Please update office.. what build is now after your update?

Comment: Sorry my word client was not updated, its working now. How i can Handle parentContentControl on old clients? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Amit, Which word client version this method is working? How it "General Exception" is resolved?

Comment: @HardikShah My client version is 1612(Build 7668.2074). and parentContentControlOrNullObject is working with it. Currently i am using beta location for api.

Comment: @Amit function insideOfContentControlCheck() {
        Word.run(function (ctx) {var myCC = ctx.document.getSelection().parentContentControlOrNullObject;
            ctx.load(myCC); // I think this is the part you are missing!
            return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                if (myCC.id) {console.log(myCC.title);// if there is a content control we'll show the title
                }
            });
        }).catch(function (e) {//there is no ContentControl.
            console.log("Error", e.message);
        });
I am not getting control id.
    }

Answer (score 1):

This is Microsoft Office word 2016 version issue. 
Same code working fine in **16.0.7571.7095.** but not working other word 2016 version.

```html
 function insideOfContentControlCheck() {
        Word.run(function (ctx) {
            var myCC = ctx.document.getSelection().parentContentControl;
            ctx.load(myCC); // I think this is the part you are missing!
            return ctx.sync()
            .then(function () {
                console.log(myCC.title);// if there is a content control we'll show the title

            });


        }).catch(function (e) {
            //there is no ContentControl.
            console.log("Error", e.message);

        });

    }
```

Comment: We have found the solution for "General Exception". You can use parentContentControlOrNullObject instead of parentContentControl. It is working fine in latest word version.

Answer (score 0):

this is the good way to check `parentSectionOrNullObject`.

```js
 await Word.run(async (context) => {
     let html;
     const range = context.document.getSelection();
     range.load('parentContentControlOrNullObject');
     await context.sync();
     const contentControl = range.parentContentControlOrNullObject;
     if (!contentControl.isNull) {
console.log("there is parentContentControlOrNullObject in current Selection")
     }else{
      console.log("there is not parentContentControlOrNullObject in current Selection")
     }
     await context.sync();
     console.log(html.value);
 })
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: @JeremyCaney  okay I will.